# How to prevent a list from outgrowing the parent <div>?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, overflow

I have a list (`#this-list`) with a input box beneath it. When a user submits the input box then the value is added to the list `#this-list` (this is handeled in react.js). When there are many items in the list, the list causes the parent `<div>` to resize. How can I limit the size of the list to the filled height and when the list starts to outgrow, show scrollbars?

```
...
        <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
            <div class="flex-fill scroll-y">
                <ul id="this-list">
                  <li>test</li>
                  <li>test</li>
                  <li>test</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
...
```

Page when to list is empty: https://jsfiddle.net/tomwassing/g7dkLx1h/

Page when the list is filled: https://jsfiddle.net/tomwassing/u80wqj3s/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a height or max-height to the ul element and add overflow-y: scroll

```
#this-list {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u80wqj3s/10/

Comment: Is there no way to implement this without hardcoded values?

Comment: Either way, you have to specify a height for the element otherwise it will automatically resize to it's content

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here seems to be that you don't limit your divs'height, letting them take on the contrary all the place they need (`height` is `auto` by default).

A way to solve the problem would be to had a JS script which would calculate the height taken by your left column, and them send the value to the right one :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
    let leftForm = document.getElementById("left-form");
    let leftHeight = Number(
        getComputedStyle(leftForm).getPropertyValue("height").slice(0,-2));

    let rightForm = document.getElementById("rightForm");
    let rightFormHeight = Number(
        getComputedStyle(rightForm).getPropertyValue("height").slice(0,-2));
    myDiv.style.setProperty("max-height",leftHeight - rightFormHeight + "px");
})
```

Of course you'll need to add `overflow: scroll` or `overflow-y: scroll` to "myDiv" (the div containing your overflowing list).